# two FB like button in the same page with different title , description and picture

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, google-plus, addthis

Is it possible to add two button like on the same page:

- The first: referencing `http://www.mysite.com`, with a title, image and description specific to the home page
- The second: referencing `http://www.mysite.com/article?id=511`, with a title, description, and image specific to article 511.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [open graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) documentation, as you need to serve the correct tags depending on which page you're on.

For example, on the home page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Site Name" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="img" />
```

And on the article page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Article Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mysite.com/article?id=511" />
<meta property="og:image" content="img2" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My article description" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site Name" />
```

Then just serve Like buttons to those different URLs on whatever page you want.

Comment: I think I have explained badly, or else I misunderstood your response :)

I wish I had two buttons on a page:
-the first : specific for site in header for the entire site "like the site" 
-the second: specific for article in body "like article" .

both in the same page.

It is possible to use many meta OG in the same page??

Comment: No, it's one set of meta tags per object. But once you have each object configured, you can have as many like buttons as you want on a page, referencing different objects. So you'll need to set up two separate pages with two separate sets of tags, then you reference those pages in your `fb:like` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes just set the href attribute on each like button to the appropriate URL.